# Arrangement of the words "SWEETNESS" in a $3 × 3$ matrix

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of ways in which all the letters of the words "SWEETNESS" can be arranged in matrix of $3 × 3$ such that no letter in any row or column is repeated:

My approach is as follow

[image]

The image is one of the possible arrangement where rows and column are different, how do we find the arrangement.  In the figure $a_{ij}$ represent the matrix in rows and column arrangement

Comment: What do you mean by "the image is the only possible arrangement"? Certainly if you have one valid arrangement you can get others (e.g. permute the rows or columns, swap Es with Ss, permute the TWN).

Comment: I will change it to one of the possible arrangement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can find the number of ways to arrange the letters by putting letters in in a sensible order and analyzing the number of choices we have at each step. Starting with the blank matrix:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
\square&\square&\square\\
\square&\square&\square\\
\square&\square&\square
\end{matrix}\right]$$

There are clearly $9$ ways to place the first $S$ into the matrix. I'll be putting letters in the example matrix arbitrarily, but each step should be valid for any previous choices.

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
S&{\color{red}\square}&{\color{red}\square}\\
{\color{red}\square}&{\color{}\square}&\square\\
{\color{red}\square}&\square&\square
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Note that after blocking out the row and column of our first $S$, there are $4$ choices for the next.

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
S&{\color{red}\square}&{\color{red}\square}\\
{\color{red}\square}&{\color{red}\square}&S\\
{\color{red}\square}&\square&{\color{red}\square}
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now there is only one square which is valid for the last $S$.

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
S&{\color{}\square}&{\color{}\square}\\
{\color{}\square}&{\color{}\square}&S\\
{\color{}\square}&S&{\color{}\square}
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Now note that the $S$'s cannot be distinguished from each other. Thus each possible configuration has been counted once for each order of the $S$'s, so we must divide by $3!=6$.

Next, we have $6$ options for the first $E$.

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
S&E&{\color{red}\square}\\
{\color{}\square}&{\color{red}\square}&S\\
{\color{}\square}&S&{\color{}\square}
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Note that since there is an $S$ in every row and column, there is one $S$ each in the same row and column as the $E$. Thus there is $1$ $S$ in the $4$ remaining squares. But as you can see below, one of the configurations leaves no options for the last $E$. So we have $2$ choices here.

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
S&E&{\color{red}\square}\\
{\color{orange}\square}&{\color{red}\square}&S\\
{\color{orange}E}&S&{\color{orange}\square}
\end{matrix}\right]\qquad\left[\begin{matrix}
S&E&{\color{red}\square}\\
{\color{lime}\square}&{\color{red}\square}&S\\
{\color{orange}\square}&S&{\color{lime}E}
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Again we have only one choice for the last $E$, and must account for $3!=6$ double-countings.

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
S&E&{\color{}\square}\\
E&{\color{}\square}&S\\
{\color{}\square}&S&E
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Finally, we have a $N$, $T$, and $W$ to place in the remaining $3$ places. There are $3!$ ways to do this:

$$\left[\begin{matrix}
S&E&{\color{lime}T}\\
E&{\color{lime}W}&S\\
{\color{lime}N}&S&E
\end{matrix}\right]$$

Going back through all our choices, we get that the total number of valid matricies is:

$$N=\frac{9\cdot4\cdot1\cdot6\cdot2\cdot1\cdot3!}{3!\cdot3!}=72$$

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 `S` and 3 `E`, so first put one `S` and one `E` in each group such there is not duplicates in the columns:
$$[S, E, \cdot][S,\cdot ,E ][\cdot, S,E ]$$
Then you need to situate only the three letters left `WTN`. There are $3!$ ways to situate those three letters, by wich there are $3!$ ways to arrange the three rows, by wich there are $2!$ ways to arrange letters `E` and `S` at the same time, so the number you are looking for is $$2\cdot3!^2=72$$

Comment: Does this keep the columns from having duplicates?

Comment: @Angelica, my bad, i only focus on one axis, i am goint to fixe it

Answer (score 0):

First choose the 3 positions of "S" by choosing a permutation$~\pi$ of$~\{1,2,3\}$ (using it for instance to map row indices to the corresponding column with an "S"), which can be done in $3!=6$ ways. Then similarly select the $3$ positions with "E" by choosing another such permutation$~\sigma$; here the choice is limited by the fact that $\sigma(i)\neq\pi(i)$ for $i=1,2,3$, which means that $\pi^{-1}\sigma$ has no fixed points, and there are $2$ possibilities (the cyclic permutations of order$~3$) for $\pi^{-1}\sigma$, and therefore as many for $\sigma$ (one could use the formula for derangement counting here but just listing is easier). Finally fill in the remaining $3$ letters in $3!$ ways, for $72$ solutions in all.